# How to tell if Apple Push Notification Service APNS is alive

Tags: iphone, push-notification

We are testing an application that has APNS and have noticed that sometimes the APNS service for the sandbox environment stops "pushing".  The message is successfully received by the apple server, no errors. There are no incoming messages from the feedback service either (we have successfully received feedback on other things). Our codebase for this feature has not changed in a while and has been working rock solid.

My question is, does Apple have some kind of ping that we can send to let us know that the sandbox APNS is alive and working?

Thanks.

Comment: What language are you using on the server side?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the only way to tell if the service is not working is if your socket connection has issues.

In testing I did find that my deviceId was incorrect at one point and was preventing me from receiving the messages.

Also, not all message delivery is guaranteed, I believe that only the last one sent is guaranteed. Are you receiving any messages from the batch?

The last question would be the type of device that you are testing with, iPod Touches don't get a push the same way that the iPhone does.

If everything on your side checks out maybe you should file a bug report/feature request with apple. [Apple Bug Reporter](https://bugreport.apple.com/) From the apple dev forums it seems like this is a much requested feature.

Answer (score 1):

i tried the following code (PHP)

```
$apnsHost = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
$apnsPort = 2195;
$apnsCert = 'apple_push_notification_production.pem';

$streamContext = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);

$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);
if($apns)
{
    echo "Connection Established<br/>";
    $deviceToken = '**********';//masked

    $body = array();
    $body['aps'] = array(’alert’ => "test message");
    //$body['aps']['badge'] = 1;

    $payload = json_encode($body);


    $apnsMessage = chr(0) . pack("n",32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . pack("n",strlen($payload)) . $payload;
    print "sending message :" . $apnsMessage . "<br/>";
    print "sending payload :" . $payload . "<br/>";
    //fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);

}
else
{   
    echo "Connection Failed";

    echo $errorString;
    echo $error;
}
socket_close($apns);
fclose($apns);
```

reply is Connection Established
sending message :�� d^÷Îå0ZCd%1ÄuwOOYš'ÊÈ}ârðm¾Í�,{"aps":{"\u2019alert\u2019":"test message"}}
sending payload :{"aps":{"\u2019alert\u2019":"test message"}}

But am not able to get the notification

any help?

Comment: @Kamal:
try to uncommon  //fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);
then you should get your notification.